# Rotation matrix in a non-orthonormal basis.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have no idea how to approach this sort of problem. I have a non-orthonormal basis $\vec{f_{1}}=\vec{e_{1}}+\vec{e_{2}}$ and $\vec{f_{2}}=\vec{e_{1}}-2\vec{e_{2}}$ where {$\vec{e_{i}}$} is an orthonormal basis. How to find a rotation matrix at $\theta$ angle?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Ok so you will need two steps to finish this one.

1. Matrix formula for basis transformation.
2. Matrix formula for rotation in ON basis.

and then put them together. You now have the pieces of information you need to put together.

Go get 'em!

Comment: So, I will have two matrices: one active and one passive, won't it?

Comment: @Camillus hmm I'm not sure what passive and active matrices are, but maybe.